Error number -1700 with account type in AppleScript with Mail application
I have an AppleScript:
tell application "Mail"
    set userAccount to "computer.ksenia.kravchenko@gmail.com"
    check for new mail for userAccount
end tell

But I have the problem:
error "Mail received a mistake: It was not possible to convert "computer.ksenia.kravchenko@gmail.com" to account type." number -1700 from "computer.ksenia.kravchenko@gmail.com" to account
I tried to use different types of emails, accounts, but every time same error

You need to actually specify a Mail account (a string containing an email address is not an account).  Note that a filter reference form (whose|where|that clause) can be used to match an account based on a property - see Mail's scripting dictionary.
